# An Image share to Multiple activities

Tags: java, android

[image]

Hi all, I would like to add an image to the right top corner that shares same data such as talking time, OnClickListener to all the activities like WeChat.

I have an xml as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calling"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorActive">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:scaleX="0.8"
            android:scaleY="0.8"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/phone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But i don't know how to achieve this feature. I tried to use base activity and  this xml to all activities that i want. It looks not quite make sense. FAB? or even more complicated. I have searched a lot online and there is no similar example like this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look into adding a fragment to an existing fragment container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the xml you posted in a separete layout file (say call_button.xml)

Now create an activity with name `BaseActivity` and make all your other activities extend it.

In the xml of your all other activities, add the following code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/callButton"
    layout="@layout/call_button" />
```

Now in your `BaseActivity` handle the click.

```
findViewById(R.id.callButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do your task.
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Nabin, first thanks for reply, I would like to know when i intent a new activity from main activity that has the call_button.xml shown, would there be two call_button.xml shown at the same time? one in main activity, one in new activity?

Comment: There will not be.